# Fishpig's Magento-Wordpress Intergration Admin Menu Not Functioning

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, fishpig

I have installed Fishpig's Wordpress integration module (v 2.4.93) into Magento 1.7.0.2. Since then I have set it up correctly and posted multiple posts to it.

However, the integrated Wordpress menu in the the Magento admin back end started to not function anymore.

Any option I choose from the admin->Wordpress->Wordpress menu now prompts me to download a .php file instead of it rendering.

Does any one know why this would be?
Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Sincerely,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting on your server which causes the PHP file to be downloaded rather than executed. Contact your hosts who should be able to fix this for you.